# Spotfire Package Builder [Deploy to server error] - Assembly Name Invalid

Tags: deployment, package, builder, spotfire

I created my first Spotfire extension project. I used the Packaged Builder to "Validate and Save" my extension [without any issues].

"Run Configuration" also works.

However when I try to "Deploy to Server..." I am getting the below error: "Not a valid AssemblyName"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

### Server Log:

```
ERROR 2017-02-20T1
6:15:50,951-0500 [user1, #828] ws.deployments.ClientDeploymentService: A runtime exception occured.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value 'CfgFileManager, Version=1.0.6260.29031, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not a valid AssemblyName.
    at com.spotfire.ws.deployments.AssemblyName.<init>(AssemblyName.java:40)
    at com.spotfire.ws.deployments.ClientModuleAssemblyMetadata.isCompatibleWith(ClientModuleAssemblyMetadata.java:69)
    at com.spotfire.ws.deployments.ClientDeploymentWorkspace.isKnownAssembly(ClientDeploymentWorkspace.java:688)
    at com.spotfire.ws.deployments.ClientDeploymentWorkspace.validate(ClientDeploymentWorkspace.java:552)
    at com.spotfire.ws.deployments.ClientDeploymentHandler.deployWorkspace(ClientDeploymentHandler.java:293)
    at com.spotfire.ws.deployments.ClientDeploymentService.deployWorkspace(ClientDeploymentService.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor239.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:251)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:123)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.CustomAuthFilterWrapper.doFilter(CustomAuthFilterWrapper.java:71)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.HstsFilter.doFilter(HstsFilter.java:137)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:86)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.HttpMethodsFilter.doFilter(HttpMethodsFilter.java:203)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.HttpMethodsFilter.doFilter(HttpMethodsFilter.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:85)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:49)
    at com.spotfire.server.security.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value 'CfgFileManager, Version=1.0.6260.29031, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
This 'PublicKeyToken=null' error indicates that the custom extension is not signed.Spotfire extensions must be signed with a strong name key.
You would need to sign the assembly under the Extension - Properties - Signing -Sign the Assembly.You can use the SpotfireDeveloper.snk file for signing ,this ships with the SDK itself.